# Optimizing collision detection in Actionscript 3.

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, collision-detection

I'm trying to make my first game in Actionscript 3. Its a simple artillery game where you have a gun at bottom left corner and AIs flying across the screen which you have to shoot down. Now, in a classing shooter game how this is achieved is either by firing a bullet from the gun and doing a hitTest of that bullet with the AI movieClip or by simply removing(or playing the death animation) the AI movieclip. But here's the problem. I dont wanna do either of them. I want to show a gun with a rapid fire rate and hence no bullets. And I also don't want the player to click exactly ON the AI movieclip to destroy them (just the gun/turret pointing at the correct direction should be enough). So here's what I tried.

This image should help picture the whole thing.

[image]

1. Tried attaching a 'line' to the turret and checking for collision with AI clip. This obviously failed because of the bounding box problem when the line is slanting.
2. I tried putting multiple tiny movieClips ON the line and iterate through them in a loop and checking for any collision with the AI. This method partially worked, but it was too slow and didn't seem like the 'correct' method.
3. I draw 2 hypothetical lines. One between p1 and p2 and other connecting p3 and p4 (please see the image above). p3----p4's lenght = AI.width and is a horizontal line running right through the center of the AI MovieClip. Upon mouseClick I check for any intersection between these two lines. Now if I have multiple AIs on the screen, Again i need to iterate through each of them, draw a fresh p3-----p4 and check for intersection with p1-----p2.

I'm using method 3 right now and I have a feeling that once I start adding more stuff to the game, framerate will take a hit. I'm sure there should a more simple/optimized method of doing this (maybe something brutally simple). Attaching some relevant code.

shipGame.as

```
var baseAI:BaseAI;
var AIList:Array= new Array;
public function shipGame():void{
            trace("still connected!!");
            /*
            irrelevant code..
            */
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateGame);
            var a:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
            aiTimer = setInterval(StartAI, 2000);
}
public function StartAI():void {
            baseAI = new BaseAI(this);
            AIList.push(baseAI);
}

public function updateGame(event:Event):void    {
            /*
            code to rotate the turret here..
            */

            for (var i:int = 0; i < AIList.length; i++) 
            {
                if (AIList[i].myx < 100) {
                    AIList[i].basicAI.parent.removeChild(AIList[i].basicAI);
                    AIList.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }

            if (mouseDn) {
                basicTurret.gotoAndPlay(2);// Fire animation
                for (var j:int = 0; j < AIList.length; j++) 
                {
                    if ( intersection(AIList[j])) // intersection(bai:BaseAI) returns boolean. Works fine. 
                    {
                        AIList[j].shot = true;
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

BaseAI.as

```
var main:shipGame;
var myy:Number;
var myy:Number;
public function BaseAI(doc:shipGame):void{
            main = doc;
            basicAI = new BasicAI(); // BasicAI is a movieClip in the library
            main.addChild(basicAI);
            basicAI.x = 400;
            basicAI.y = Math.abs(Math.random() * (280)) + 20;
            myy = basicAI.y;
            basicAI.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, keepMoving);
}

public function keepMoving(evt:Event):void {
        basicAI.x -= 5;
        myx = basicAI.x;

        if (shot && alive) {
            alive = false;
            basicAI.gotoAndPlay(2);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your current methods are essentially relying on Flash's renderer to know where the ships and bullet-lines are. But in your case, since you have a relatively simple geometric relationship between the moving parts, it would be much faster to handle the problem analytically.

Consider the case where a ship is sitting precisely on your gun's line of fire. In this case the gun, ship and bottom of the screen form a right triangle. If we define `theta` to be the angle between the gun and the bottom of the screen, then the following will hold:

```
tangent(theta) = ship.y / ship.x
```

where `x` and `y` are measured rightwards and upwards from the gun. Now you can generalize this and use it for your hit testing. When the gun is fired, first find `theta`. Then for each ship, you can easily determine how far vertically or horizontally the ship is from the line of fire, by doing something like this:

```
var theta = /*determine theta based on where the mouse was clicked*/
var tanTheta = tangent(theta);
for each (ship) {
    var gunX = ship.y / tanTheta;
    if ( abs(gunX - ship.x) < ship.width/2 ) {
        // a hit occurred
    }
}
```

That's just pseudocode but hopefully you get the idea. Anyway that's how I would do it - this will scale hugely faster than anything you do with real hit testing, and for the described case it should work just as well.